# How to solve the error when connecting to a Database as a Service from my hosting site?

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting, dbaas

I utilized a free hosting service called 00webhost.com for hosting php-MySQL app. The database was then uploaded to a xeround.com which provides Database-as-a-Service. xeround.com gave url=instancexxxxx.db.xeround.com:57xx as well as a username and password. But 00webhost.com gave the following error:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'instancexxxxx.db.xeround.com' (4)

How do I solve this?

Comment: $conet = mysql_connect("instancexxxx.db.xeround.com:57xx", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxxx");

mysql_select_db("xxxxxxx", $conet);  

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xxxxxx");

Comment: Use a real web host. There is undoubtedly something wrong with the free host you're using, and no chance they'll fix it given that you're not paying for the service.

Comment: Does adding the port number along with url cause any problem while dB connection?

Comment: has your database become 'active'? This error comes when the server is not running.

Comment: Have you whitelisted/added a user with the IP you are connection from on the MySql server?

Comment: 5quidhosting offer a free account with a local DB, http://www.5quidhost.co.uk/hosting.php

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd check is that the database has the option for external access turned on, judging by the connect string it probably is...but you never know